# Send 2 Different Emails to 2 Different Recipients?

Tags: php, email

i have a registration form that allows users to register and become members on my site. So far once they register their details this goes in the database and they get an email sent out to say thanks.

I am trying to duplicate the script so that i can send a different email letting me know when a users registered and have this sent to my email.

I'm trying to do it this way because the email that gets sent out to the user contains a randomly generated md5 hash code that i also need to have sent to me in the email sent to me telling me they've registered.

I've managed to get the two emails to deliver to the correct email accounts. however, the email being sent to me letting me know a user has signed up is also being sent to the user and i don't want it to go to them?

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong? Thanks

CODE to send email to user:

```
<?php

/**
 * ShuttleCMS - A basic CMS coded in PHP.
 * code generator - Used for allowing a user to generate a code
 * 
 * @author Dan <dan@danbriant.com>
 * @version 0.0.1
 * @package ShuttleCMS
 */
define('IN_SCRIPT', true);
// Start a session
session_start();

/*
 * Generates new code and puts it on database
 */

//Generate a RANDOM MD5 Hash for a code
$random_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

//Take the first 8 digits and use them as the password we intend to email the user
$emailcode=substr($random_code, 0, 8);

//Encrypt $emailpassword in MD5 format for the database
$registrationcode=($emailcode);

// Make a safe query
$query = sprintf("UPDATE `ptb_registrations` SET `registration_code` = '%s' WHERE email = \"$email\"",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($registrationcode));

mysql_query($query)or die('Could not update members: ' . mysql_error());

?>

<?php

 $subjectconfirm = " Thanks for your Registration";
 $headersconfirm = "To: $email\r\n"; 
 $headersconfirm .= "From: siteindex.com <registrations@siteindex>\r\n";                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 $headersconfirm .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

  $sep = sha1(date('r', time()));
 $bodyconfirm = <<< EOF

(EMAIL BODY)

EOF;


 // Finally, send the email
 mail($email, $subjectconfirm, $bodyconfirm, $headersconfirm);

?>
```

Then i'm duplicating the code like this but replacing the to email address. and it sends to my email account fine but it sends both emails to the user and i don't want them getting the email intended for me.

Code to have email sent to me:

```
<?php

    /**
     * ShuttleCMS - A basic CMS coded in PHP.
     * code generator - Used for allowing a user to generate a code
     * 
     * @author Dan <dan@danbriant.com>
     * @version 0.0.1
     * @package ShuttleCMS
     */
    define('IN_SCRIPT', true);
    // Start a session
    session_start();

    /*
     * Generates new code and puts it on database
     */

    //Generate a RANDOM MD5 Hash for a code
    $random_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

    //Take the first 8 digits and use them as the password we intend to email the user
    $emailcode=substr($random_code, 0, 8);

    //Encrypt $emailpassword in MD5 format for the database
    $registrationcode=($emailcode);

    // Make a safe query
    $query = sprintf("UPDATE `ptb_registrations` SET `registration_code` = '%s' WHERE email = \"$email\"",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($registrationcode));

    mysql_query($query)or die('Could not update members: ' . mysql_error());

    ?>

    <?php

     $subjectconfirm = " Thanks for your Registration";
     $headersconfirm = "To: signups@siteindex.com\r\n"; 
     $headersconfirm .= "From: siteindex.com <signups@siteindex>\r\n";                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     $headersconfirm .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

      $sep = sha1(date('r', time()));
     $bodyconfirm = <<< EOF

    (DIFFERENT EMAIL BODY)

    EOF;


     // Finally, send the email
     mail($email, $subjectconfirm, $bodyconfirm, $headersconfirm);

    ?>
```

Comment: lots of code. just send it to the user, with their email. then send it to your self, with your email

Comment: thanks would you be able to explain a little what you mean, like an example if possible thanks.

Comment: Can you just BCC yourself so that you need only send one email?

Answer (score 3):

You'll notice from the [mail manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), the first parameter is where the email is sent to. You haven't changed it. You have only changed the header. In order to send an email to someone else, change:

```
mail($email, $subjectconfirm, $bodyconfirm, $headersconfirm);
```

to:

```
mail('signups@siteindex.com', $subjectconfirm, $bodyconfirm, $headersconfirm);
```

Of course, it is far more sensible to just BCC it to yourself instead of duplicating all this code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need to duplicate the code. Just send two emails:

```
$emails = 'youremail@email.com, theiremail@email.com';
mail($emails, $subjectconfirm, $bodyconfirm, $headersconfirm);
```

Or BCC yourself:

```
$headersconfirm .= 'Bcc: youremail@email.com' . "\r\n";
```

Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: Including `youremail@email.com` as a BCC recipient is probably preferable over a TO recipient, but otherwise you're correct... There's no need to duplicate any code here.